# ChatVRMにてcharcoalを適用した、TailwindCSSの他クラスが反映されない

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, tailwindcss

以下にて質問したにですが、解答が得られないためこちらでも失礼いたします。
https://teratail.com/questions/qcs66ekjgitvdl

#### 実現したいこと

ソース「ChatVRM」
https://github.com/pixiv/ChatVRM

こちらを元に開発しております。
TailwindCSSのピクシブさんが作られたcharcoalが使用されています。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

`npm run dev` でローカル起動している際、最初に設定されている以外のTailwindCSSのクラスが適用されません。

例えば `src\components\githubLink.tsx` の12行目

```
<div className="p-16 rounded-16 bg-[#1F2328] hover:bg-[#33383E] active:bg-[565A60] flex">
```

こちらの「p-16」を「p-17」等に設定しても、反映がされない次第です。

申し訳ございません、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/qcs66ekjgitvdl) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Comment: ありがとうございます、そのように編集いたします。